# Toggle does not work on the same element that show works on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use JQuery toggle, so when a user clicks the info icon, the hidden div containing item information is shown / hidden. For some reason it is not working for me.

While trying to debug, I noticed that show(), correctly shows the target element that I would like to toggle. However, when I replace `show()` with `toggle()`, it does not work and does not return any error.

I was wondering if someone can help me identify the cause of this problem.

My Markup

```
<div class="option">    
    <div class="prod-text">Toy Whistle </div>
    <div>
        <img class="info-icon" src="Info-icon.png">
    </div>
    <div class="option-info" style="display:none;">
        <div>
            <div class="price-text">Price: $100</div>
            <div class="prod-id-text">Item Number: 231912</div>
            <div class="quantity-text">Quantity: 72</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery (does not work)

```
$(".info-icon").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.option-info').toggle();
});
```

JQuery (works!)

```
$(".info-icon").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.option-info').show();
});
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/a2pDx/. Can you provide more info or a runnable example?

Comment: it's working here in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bZ4j9/

Comment: @esker, thanks for the reply. I was trying to, but it is way too much code:/ Any suggestions on how to begin debug such a problem? The code above is generated after an AJAX call. So there is AJAX, JavaScript, and a lot of markup involved (1000+ lines all together), otherwise I would post it...

Comment: What would explain the `show()` working and `toggle()` not working on the same selected element? its such a bizarre problem, I don't even know how to try to fix it:(

Comment: In your application where you see the error, does the `.find()` return the same expected set of elements each time?  That is one thing I would investigate.  I would also investigate the initial state of the element.  It may be that your first call to `.toggle()` performs the opposite transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the click event handler is getting bound twice, and thus fire twice for each click. The `show()` would work fine in this case, but the `toggle()` would show and then immediately hide the element each time you click. Try this:

```
$(".info-icon").click(function(){
    console.log('click handler fired');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.option-info').toggle();
});
```

And run this with Web Inspector or Firebug enabled to see how many messages are logged for each click.

Comment: +1, thank you very much for the help @esker! I ended up fixing the problem using your `console.log` advice, what a great debugging tool, never used it before!

Comment: I appreciate it :) The problem was due to having the `info-icon` click event listener inside an hover event listener, and it caused it to fire many times for no reason. Now it is firing only once per click.